# Migrate question to U&L

Tags: support

I asked this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/817747/ext4-or-ntfs-lost-all-files-of-the-last-2-years-how-can-i-recover-them

I did it wrong because I initially thought that ServerFault was for "system administration" and it is later I realized it is "system administration only in the pro environment and explicitly excluding home and devel setups".

I feel now that the question should be in Unix&Linux.

Question: Would it be possible to remove the negative votes, clear it from SF and migrate it to U&L?

Comment: I'm not even convinced your question was entirely off-topic, just poorly received because it is a clear development / home environment. Regardless, a lot of people end up in the same situation as you when posting here and you took it very well, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Seems fine to me. I migrated your question to Unix & Linux.

There's nothing we can do about the downvotes; those are up to the individual users.

The question itself will remain for a few days as a redirect to point people over to U&L, and then the system will delete it.